# Optimize combinational MongoDB query in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have ten stations stored in the `stations` collection: `Station A`, `Station B`, `Station C`, `Station D`, `Station E`, `Station F`, `Station G`, `Station H`, `Station I`, `Station J`.

Right now, to create a count list of all inter-station rides between all possible pairs of stations, I do the following in my Node.js code (using Mongoose):

```js
const stationCombinations = []

// get all stations from the stations collection
const stationIds = await Station.find({}, '_id name').lean().exec()

// list of all possible from & to combinations with their names
stationIds.forEach(fromStation => {
  stationIds.forEach(toStation => {
    stationCombinations.push({ fromStation, toStation })
  })
})

const results = []

// loop through all station combinations
for (const stationCombination of stationCombinations) {
  // create aggregation query promise
  const data = Ride.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        test: false,
        state: 'completed',
        duration: { $gt: 2 },
        fromStation: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(stationCombination.fromStation._id),
        toStation: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(stationCombination.toStation._id)
       }
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: null,
        count: { $sum: 1 }
      }
    },
    {
      $addFields: {
        fromStation: stationCombination.fromStation.name,
        toStation: stationCombination.toStation.name
      }
    }
  ])

  // push promise to array
  results.push(data)
}

// run all aggregation queries
const stationData = await Promise.all(results)

// flatten nested/empty arrays and return
return stationData.flat()
```

Executing this function give me the result in this format:

```js
[
  {
    "fromStation": "Station A",
    "toStation": "Station A",
    "count": 1196
  },
  {
    "fromStation": "Station A",
    "toStation": "Station B",
    "count": 1
  },
  {
    "fromStation": "Station A",
    "toStation": "Station C",
    "count": 173
  },
]

And so on for all other combinations...
```

The query currently takes a lot of time to execute and I keep getting alerts from MongoDB Atlas about excessive load on the database server because of these queries. Surely there must be an optimized way to do something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use MongoDB native operations. You need to `$group` by `fromStation` and `toStation` and with `$lookup` join two collections.

**Note:** I assume you have MongoDB >=v3.6 and `Station._id` is `ObjectId`

```
db.ride.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      test: false,
      state: "completed",
      duration: {
        $gt: 2
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        fromStation: "$fromStation",
        toStation: "$toStation"
      },
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "station",
      let: {
        fromStation: "$_id.fromStation",
        toStation: "$_id.toStation"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $in: [
                "$_id",
                [
                  "$$fromStation",
                  "$$toStation"
                ]
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "tmp"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      fromStation: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$tmp",
          initialValue: "",
          in: {
            $cond: [
              {
                $eq: [
                  "$_id.fromStation",
                  "$$this._id"
                ]
              },
              "$$this.name",
              "$$value"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      toStation: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$tmp",
          initialValue: "",
          in: {
            $cond: [
              {
                $eq: [
                  "$_id.toStation",
                  "$$this._id"
                ]
              },
              "$$this.name",
              "$$value"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      count: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      fromStation: 1,
      toStation: 1
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fJHjjDkv3aE)

Not tested:

```
const data = Ride.aggregate([
  {
     $match: {
       test: false,
       state: 'completed',
       duration: { $gt: 2 }
     }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        fromStation: "$fromStation",
        toStation: "$toStation"
      },
      count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "station",
      let: {
        fromStation: "$_id.fromStation",
        toStation: "$_id.toStation"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $in: [
                "$_id",
                [
                  "$$fromStation",
                  "$$toStation"
                ]
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "tmp"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      fromStation: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$tmp",
          initialValue: "",
          in: {
            $cond: [
              {
                $eq: [
                  "$_id.fromStation",
                  "$$this._id"
                ]
              },
              "$$this.name",
              "$$value"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      toStation: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$tmp",
          initialValue: "",
          in: {
            $cond: [
              {
                $eq: [
                  "$_id.toStation",
                  "$$this._id"
                ]
              },
              "$$this.name",
              "$$value"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      count: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      fromStation: 1,
      toStation: 1
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: What indexes would you suggest adding for this query? While doing `explain`, I can see that this query has to scan the entire database during execution.